# Does Paw app have support for HTTP/2

Tags: paw-app

Does Paw app support HTTP/2?

If so is there something specifically I have to do to get it to use it over 1.2?

If it does not currently are there plans to add support?

Comment: Sorry for late @kdbdallas, Paw doesn't support HTTP/2 for now, but it's definitively in the pipeline...

Comment: @MichaMazaheri, What about now?

Comment: Not now, we're considering to support HTTP/2 for downstream connections (push), but probably not anytime soon for concurrent writes. What's your specific use case @IulianOnofrei?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri We talked already via email the other day :)

Comment: @MichaMazaheri I'd also love to see this for testing and verification purposes.

Comment: @danieljimenez Noted! :)

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Hi! I'm just now debugging issue with HTTP/2 where redirects would hang (only with h2) and I wanted to test it with Paw... but sadly it still doesn't support HTTP/2 in 2018, even with NSURLConnection :( I'm very sad :(

Comment: really hoping for this too... trying to debug some HTTP/2 mobile APIs and can't use Paw :'(

Comment: Is this still valid - my use case, talking with Apples APNS service, which is deprecating HTTP